# Visual Studio plugin to show the text from a resource file instead of the code

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

We've been implementing resource files for our globalisation.

Quite often I'll need to search for some text where a user is reporting a mistake or for whatever reason. Obviously now we use resource files all the text is replaced with code to go grab the required string from the resource file

Are there any features in VS or plugins that allow you to open up a cshtml page and have it show the default resource file entries rather than the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check out the String Resource Visualizer https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.StringResourceVisualizer

This extensions works fine for cs files and I hope it will work for cshtml.

Comment: Thank you, that would be exactly what I am looking for but I am not using assembled resource files and resourcemanager or Localizer (core only?) but GetLocalResourceObject/GetGlobalResourceObject. I tried it but it doesnt seem to pick those up. Thanks @Serg